# Can't find default file in WCF service on IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have WCF service project.Everything worked fine on Development Server.But I wanted to use net.tcp binding and for this I have set IIS 7.0 server in properties of WCF project.
I got a trouble, Error HTTP 404.20 - Not Found (No default document).Clinet is ASP.NET MVC 3.
Please help

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?  Development server doesn't support net.tcp and from your error it sounds like you moved to IIS?  It also sounds like you are not addressing your service with the .svc extension so that IIS is trying to lookup a default document?

Comment: Hello!Thanks for post
Yes I moved on IIS 7.0.What does it mean ot addressing your service with the .svc?I guess all my addresses is normal.load the localhost, my port, and name my project.
Which details do u need, I can provide any code.Sorry but I'm new in WCF, that's my first project on it(

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work that way. When published in IIS, a WCF service with an endpoint over net.tcp needs to have a net.tcp **site** binding.
Then, the Windows Activation Service (WAS) comes into play.
It's actually a pretty long story.

I suggest you first publish your service in IIS according to these instructions: http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/10/08/setting-up-a-nettcpbinding-enabled-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx

If it still doesn't work, then post back with extra info.

**Note:** [Extra reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx), [extra-extra reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx).